# Create tag "overtone-singing"?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a small handful of questions on the site that relate to overtone singing, but they use fairly divergent terminology so it's hard to collect them all. An `overtone-singing` tag would encompass such diverse keywords as:

- kargyraa
- sygyt
- khoomei
- throat singing
- harmonic singing

Here are a few questions that would fall under such a tag. (Yesterday I could have sworn there were more, but I fail to find them now…)

- [Exercises for Tuvan Throat-Singing (Overtone-Singing)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4647/exercises-for-tuvan-throat-singing-overtone-singing)
- [Tuvan Throat singing: Get overtones louder in sygyt style](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100884/tuvan-throat-singing-get-overtones-louder-in-sygyt-style)

What say y'all?

Comment: I wonder if we might not be better served by a broader [extended-techniques] tag, which would also encompass questions about string harmonics, brass flutter tonguing, etc. (It's worth acknowledging, however, that "extended-technique" could be considered Eurocentric, as it's common usage is relative to standard techniques on Western instruments.)

Comment: @Aaron I'm surprised there isn't already such a tag! Though I do agree with your assessment that it's kind of Eurocentric — to a kargyraa performer, kargyraa technique is "normal" technique.

Comment: I would say [overtone-singing] makes sense to me as it actually encompasses multiple different historical practices (Tibetan, Tuvan, Mongolian, etc) that have techniques that are common across them, as well as modern usage of the same (e.g. in prog rock or whatever).

Comment: I wonder if there's some other term that would serve the same purpose. By having a voice-specific tag plus, presumably, a different tag for other instruments, it creates a potential tagging/searching problem. I would know to look for an [extended-techniques] tag, because it's a common term across all types of instruments, but I wouldn't know to search for [overtone-singing] unless I read through the list of all possible tags. Maybe we can come up with a term that means what "extended-techniques" is trying to convey but without the implied Eurocentrism. Some kind of "technique-*" term, ...?